# How to efficiently replace characters in XML document in Java?

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, replace

I'm looking for a neat and efficient way to replace characters in XML document. There is a replacement table defined for almost 12.000 UTF-8 characters, most of them are to be replaced by single characters, but some must be replaced by two or even three characters (e.g. Greek theta should become TH). The documents can be bulky (100MB+). How to do it in Java? I came up with the idea of using XSLT, but I'm not too sure if this is the best option.

Comment: One good way is to create a 16 bit lookup table and use the character value to performance lookup and replace. this is what XML parsers do to check character validity

Comment: @vtd-xml-author: so you mean it only works for Unicode 3.0?  How would that work for UTF-8 encoded XML files containing codepoints above 65535?

Comment: good point. According to the question, it seems that it won't go above 16 bit because the post says the characters are "replaced by two or even three characters."

Comment: @vtd-xml-author: eh :)  I was actually asking about the XML parsers checking for character validity that you mentioned: are they not supporting Unicode 3.1+ or do they use some other tricks in addition to the lookup table (which is an idea I like very much)?  I mean, an XML parser parsing an UTF-8 file should accept Unicode 3.1 and newer codepoints right?!   (I am confused by that 16-bit lookup table you mentioned :)

Comment: the short answer is that xml parsers do check validity of char above 16-bit, that part is by using simple comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String.replace(..) is very slow, based on my experience. I used to parse 100MB KML files using that API and the performance is just bad. Then, I pre-compiled the regular expression using Pattern.compile(..) and that worked whole lot faster.

Comment: Good point.  Blinded by the fact that there's no need to treat it as XML, I entirely forgot to think about the best solution for the Java part of it.

Comment: As I said the replacement is not straightforward 'foo' to 'bar'. There is big mapping table defined that contains 12.000 replacements. This is why I was considering loading the mapping to HashMap<Character,String> and then checking each character of textual content of XML tags against that map. What about that?

Comment: Yes, I think you need that mapping table whether it's in a map or if you are storing in a database and have Hibernate to handle that caching for you. Perhaps, you can have a precompiled regex that scans the entire XML to look for non-alpha-numeric characters first, then for each of these characters, check against the map to see if such character exists, if it does then create another precompiled regex to perform that particular character replacement. 

Maybe, this is not the best solution, but I'm just throwing out ideas here.

Comment: To add a little more to my strategy above, the whole point is not to loop through the entire 12K keys if it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks limc. This is what we've decided to do. We'd use regexp to check if there are any nonstandard characters for the textual values and then perform replacement using mapping (in memory).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SAX which allows you to see each individual part of the XML document as they pass by.  You can then take action on text nodes and do the manipulation you need.

The problem with XSLT is that most implementations need the whole input tree in memory, which is typically 10 times the size on disk.  I only know of the commercial edition of Saxon XSLT transformer which can do streaming XSLT (but that would be perfect for your needs).